# android setting for screen hue, saturation

Tags: android, screen, hue

I want to set the screen hue and saturation
I've checked how to set screen brightness.

Something like:

```
Settings.System.putInt(cr, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 50);
```

But there aren't any options for hue, saturation.
Can I set those options?

Comment: hi i am also looking for control hue, saturation and contrast in the device setting in android, So pls let me know if u got any solution or idea about that.